# libgdx ContactListener without collision

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I have `ContactListener` connected to my world. I got an Enemy class that extends `Sprite` and Player class that extends `Sprite` as well. When they collision I do get sent to `beginContact` but then what happens is that the enemy starts to drag my player backwards, I don't want that. I want to get sent to `beginContact` when they collision but that they will not effect each other paths.

Comment: Is there  any relation between ContactListener of box2d with your Enemy and Player class which is child of Sprite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a collision to be detected, and suppress the impulse produced by that collision. There is at least two options there :

**Option 1**

Make one of the fixture a sensor. This way, you would still have a collision, but without having bodies repeling one another.

```
FixtureDef def = new FixtureDef();
def.isSensor = true;
```

**Option 2**

This might be more what you have in mind. To avoid the collision physical effetcs, you can discard a contact like this :

```
@Override
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
{
    contact.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Note that you have to keep invoking the `setEnabled(false)` every box2d world step as long as the two entities are colliding.

**MoreOn**

You can read more on how a collision work there : http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks. For sensors, informations are widely available over the internet.